Getting storage value of mapping with negative number key in JS/TS/Viem
I'm trying to find out how to access the storage value of mapping keys of negative numbers, say mapping(int => uint), in viem, but anything written in JS or TS should give me a hint of how to do it in viem.

In Solidity, mapping keys are hashed using keccak256 before being used as storage keys, like:
keccak256(abi.encode(key, slot))

Suppose, we've a contract like:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

contract StorageMapping {
    mapping(int256 => uint256) myMapping; // Storage Slot 0

    function assignMapping(int256 key, uint256 value) external {
        myMapping[key] = value;
    }

    function getMappingValue(int256 key) external view returns (uint256) {
        return myMapping[key];
    }
}

Now, we want to access the value of the mapping variable myMapping for a particular key directly from the storage slot, not by calling any getter function or so.
We can easily get the storage layout of a contract using the forge inspect command of Foundry, like:
forge inspect ContractName storageLayout

In our case, it would be like:
forge inspect StorageMapping storageLayout


So, in the contract, the mapping variable myMapping is defined at storage slot 0.
Here's the implementation in JS / TS to access the value for a particular key directly from the storage slot using ethers.js:
import { ethers } from "ethers";

async function getMappingValueFromStorageSlot(contractAddress, mappingSlot, key, provider) {

    // Encode the key and the slot
    const encodedKeySlot = (new ethers.AbiCoder()).encode(
        ["int256", "uint256"],
        [key, mappingSlot]
    );

    // Compute the keccak256 hash of the encoded data
    const storageKey = ethers.keccak256(encodedKeySlot);

    // Read the storage at the computed location
    const valueHex = await provider.getStorage(contractAddress, storageKey);

    // Convert the result to a number (or BigNumber if needed)
    const value = ethers.toBigInt(valueHex);
    return value;
}

(async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com"); // Use the RPC url of the network at which your contract is deployed
    const contractAddress = "0xB1C0bc7Ca5Fb99Fb671fCDFD9F3400b7C414204E"; // Replace with your Contract Address
    const mappingSlot = 0; // Replace with your actual slot
    const key = -42; // Replace with your negative key

    const value = await getMappingValueFromStorageSlot(contractAddress, mappingSlot, key, provider);
    console.log("Value at mapping key:", value.toString());
})();

Adapting for Viem
In viem, the process is similar, but we will use viem functions to encode and compute hashes:
import { keccak256, encodeAbiParameters, createPublicClient, http } from 'viem';
import { sepolia } from 'viem/chains';

async function getMappingValueFromStorageSlotViem(contractAddress, mappingSlot, key) {
    const client = createPublicClient({
        chain: sepolia,
        transport: http('https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com'),
    });

    const encodedKeySlot = encodeAbiParameters(
        [{ type: 'int256' }, { type: 'uint256' }],
        [key, mappingSlot]
    );

    // Compute storage key
    const storageKey = keccak256(encodedKeySlot);

    // Fetch storage value
    const valueHex = await client.getStorageAt({
        address: contractAddress,
        slot: storageKey,
    });

    return BigInt(valueHex);
}

const contractAddress = "0xB1C0bc7Ca5Fb99Fb671fCDFD9F3400b7C414204E"; // Replace with your Contract Address
const mappingSlot = 0; // Replace with your actual slot
const key = -42; // Replace with your negative key

getMappingValueFromStorageSlotViem(contractAddress, mappingSlot, key).then((value) => {
    console.log("Value at mapping key:", value.toString());
})

